# Azure Single Sign-on with Custom STS

Tags: asp.net, azure, single-sign-on, identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I am looking for a way to authenticate users in a suite of apps using my own custom STS.  The main app is built on Azure and is currently using ASP.NET identity temporarily, though the others (which are third party helpdesk and billing) supposedly support OAuth integration.  Also there is an administrator app that I want to authenticate against the same STS, but using credentials in Azure active directory.  Right now, all of the individual apps have their own user databases which is becoming a big hassle.

This seems like it should be a pretty straightforward scenario, but I can’t find any solid information.  Most everything that I find seems like it’s geared toward *just* Azure AD or *just* Facebook/Google.

BTW - Public providers like Facebook, Google, etc are out of the question, as this is an application that is used by government agencies and does not allow public signups.  Users are created by agency administrators inside the main app itself, which would (I’m assuming?) require that an account also be created automatically in the STS at the same time.

I looked at Thinktecture IdentityServer for this, and it seems to work well, but it does not provide any sort of API that I can find, so it looks like users have to be created within IdS itself manually which is a no go.

Can someone with a little more insight into these technologies guide me in the right direction? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think I'm missing something... If Azure AD is going to be your common identity store then why not just have all apps authenticate against Azure AD?

Comment: Thanks for the response - to clarify, we only want to use Azure AD for our internal staff, although ADFS is definitely something we want to leave as a future option for certain agencies.